# JAVA Splitting Strings from an array into smaller arrays to go in a method to create object?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, methods, split

I am working on a project for a beginners java course, I need to read a file and turn each line into an object, which i will eventually print out as a job listing. (please no ArrayList suggestions)
so far i have gotten that file saved into a String[], which contains strings like this:

*"iOS/Android Mobile App Developer - Java, Swift","Freshop, Inc.","$88,000 - $103,000 a year"

"Security Engineer - Offensive Security","Indeed","$104,000 - $130,000 a year"

"Front End Developer - CSS/HTML/Vue","HiddenLevers","$80,000 - $130,000 a year"*

what im having trouble with is trying to split each string into its three parts so it can be inputted into my JobService createJob method which is as shown:

```
 public Job createJob(String[] Arrs) {
       Job job = new Job();
        job.setTitle(Arrs[0]);
        job.setCompany(Arrs[1]);
        job.setCompensation(Arrs[2]);
        return job;
    }
```

I am terrible at regex but know that trying to .split(",") will break up the salary portion as well. if anyone could help figure out a reliable way to split these strings to fit into my method i would be grateful!!!
Also im super new, please use language the commoners like me will understand...

Comment: `split("\",")` would probably be more useful, as the text could contain `,`, but seems to be "grouped" by the quotes

Comment: You can split on the quote characters alone. The result array will have an empty string in the [0]th element and the job title in the [1]st element, a comman in the [2]nd element, the posting site in the [3]rd element....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a slightly better split criteria, something like `\","` for example...

```
String text = "\"iOS/Android Mobile App Developer - Java, Swift\",\"Freshop, Inc.\",\"$88,000 - $103,000 a year\"";
String[] parts = text.split("\",");
for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

Which prints...

```
"iOS/Android Mobile App Developer - Java, Swift
"Freshop, Inc.
"$88,000 - $103,000 a year"
```

Now, if you want to remove the quotes, you can do something like....

```
String text = "\"iOS/Android Mobile App Developer - Java, Swift\",\"Freshop, Inc.\",\"$88,000 - $103,000 a year\"";
String[] parts = text.split("\",");
for (String part : parts) {
    System.out.println(part.replace("\"", ""));
}
```

## Regular Expression

No, I'm not that good at it either.  I tried...

```
String[] parts = text.split("^\"|\",\"|\"$");
```

And while this works, it produces 4 elements, not 3 (first match is blank).

You could remove the first and trailing quotes and then just use `","` instead...

```
text = text.substring(1, text.length() - 2);
String[] parts = text.split("\",\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. trim leading and trailing quotes
2. split on `","`

As code:

```
String[] columns = line.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "").split("\",\"");
```

`^"|"$` means "a quote at start *or* a quote at end"

The regex for the split is just a literal `","`